# Inserting table names and the number of records in T-SQL using cursor (Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'table_x')

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, database-cursor

I receive data from a particular supplier (multiple files) and I need to log the table name as well as the number of records/table. I tried to use the following code:

```
declare 
@TableName sysname,
@sqlstring nvarchar (1000);


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Name 
FROM DataBase.dbo.Sysobjects 
WHERE name like '%SupplierName%' and crdate = '20190320';

if OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Mytable') is not null
exec ('drop table #MyTable');

create table #MyTable (
    TableName varchar (100),
    Qty int);

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tablename  


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
  set @sqlstring = N'insert into #MyTable (TableName, Qty) select  cast(' + @Tablename + N' as varchar (100)), (select count(*) from DataBase.dbo.' + quotename(@Tablename) + N' as Qty)'  
  EXECUTE master.dbo.sp_executesql @sqlstring
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tablename 
END  

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I receive an error message as follows:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'table_1'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'table_2'. (...)
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'table_n'.

which possibly means that the cursor is fetching the table names, so the error is probably in my dynamic SQL, but i wasn't able to fix it. 
I use MS Server 2012, am a relatively beginner user of SQL. would be grateful for any useful hints pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dynamic SQL is generating...

```
select  cast(Tablename as varchar (100)), (select count(*) from DataBase.dbo.[Tablename]) as Qty)
```

and you need

```
select  cast('Tablename' as varchar (100)), (select count(*) from DataBase.dbo.[Tablename]) as Qty)
```

you can solve it this way

```
set @sqlstring = N'insert into #MyTable (TableName, Qty) select  cast(' + quotename(@Tablename, '''') + N' as varchar (100)), (select count(*) from DataBase.dbo.' + quotename(@Tablename) + N' as Qty)'
```

`quootename(@Tablename, '''')` will add the missing quotation to get 'TableName' as a value, not as a reference

I would change it for, looks more readable, but it's your call

```
set @sqlstring = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName, '''') + N',COUNT(1) 
    FROM DataBase.dbo.' + quotename(@Tablename) 
INSERT #MyTable (TableName, Qty)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlstring
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tablename
```

Comment: Daniel, thanks a lot, that actually solved the issue! I wasn't aware of this usage of " quotename(@Tablename, '''') ", great hint!

Answer (score 0):

For why your statement wwasn't with that was due to the below:

```
'...cast(' + @Tablename + N' as varchar (100))...'
```

This would covert into the SQL

```
CAST(YourTableName AS varchar(100))
```

Which, you can probably see doesn't make sense. You want `YourTableName` wrapped in single quote, and probably as an `nvarchar`. you can achieve that by doing this instead:

```
    '...cast(N' + QUOTENAME(@Tablename,N'''') + N' as nvarchar (100))...'
```

Rather than using a cursor, you could far more "easily" build this into a single statement though, and use the `PRINT` to trouble shoot. This should work for your goal, but I can't test as I don't have access to your system:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(TableName sysname,
                      Qty int);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO #MyTable(TableName, Qty)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME([name],N'''') + N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME([name]) + N')'
                  FROM sys.sysobjects  --I assume this should have been sys
                  WHERE [name] LIKE N'%SupplierName%'
                    AND crdate = '20190320'
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,11,N'') + N';'
--PRINT @SQL --Your debugging best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Larnu, thanks a lot! I used a similar way to solve it but it involved a bit more manual changing of the script, that's very useful - I wasn't aware of using "stuff" this way, another great hint. I though wanted to check why my solution with the cursor didn't work as that might be more suitable in a number of tasks I will have to do with this data later ( I mean in a similar fashion). I do use the print @sql I just didn't point out the obvious, which you, helpfully did!